# How do I include a link in a backend Rails email that goes directly to the ios app like forget password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, react-native-ios, deep-linking, deeplink

I'm trying to implement Forget Password in my application and can't figure out why my link is not working correctly.

Specs:

Rails backend

React Native frontend . (set for ios)

Xcode:  Currently in TestFlight
         URL Types:  identifier: blank  , URL Schemes: com.myproject

### In Rails I have a a Mailers file named forgot_password_email_mailer.rb.  This file has the following method in it.

```
def forgot_password(user)
    @user = user
    @greeting = "Hi"
    @url = "com.myproject://"

    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Reset password instructions')
end
```

---

### this will send an email from the forgot_password.html.erb & text.erb following file under View directory

```
<%= @greeting %> <%= @user.name %>, <br>


To reset your password, click the URL below: <br>

<%=link_to "password reset" ,@link  %>



If you did not request your password to be reset, just ignore this e-mail and your password will stay the same.
```

---

now... my problem is I can't get this @link which is com.myproject:// to go directly to my ios app.  instead it's just dead and won't work.

I'm very confused about Deep Linking and how I implement it.  Most of what I find about it is 3+ years old and outdated.

Can someone please explain to me how to make an email link from rails Mailer that includes a clickable  link to the app and not to a browser address.  Point me in the right direction and make sure my setting are correct.

Thank you!

Comment: `link_to` in your mailer should use the rails route path of your reset password page, which is defined in `routes.rb`. For instance it should be something like `link_to "password reset", reset_password_url(token: @user.reset_password_token)`, but you have to adjust that with your real route name and params needed, I'm assuming here you're using a reset token

Comment: Thank you colinux,  I will check that out and see if it works.  Where does the _url come from in the reset_password_url ?  Is that based on what I have as my default_url_options in Development.rb and Production.rb files with Development being localhost:3000

Comment: Yes, `_url` helpers are the same as `_path` route helpers, except they're including the host part defined in `default_url_options`. For emails, theses options are defined under `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` key.